# Delphi: Threads and Generic

Tags: multithreading, delphi, generics

I am just trying to pass a generic type to the execute method of a TThread. I can't figure it out...

```
procedure MyThread.Execute;
begin
  Obj := TDWResponseType.FromJsonString<T>(Response);
end;
```

Should I use a threadvar, How can I cast It ?

Comment: It depends. We can't really see enough of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can't you just create a generic `TMyThread<T>` class that extends `TThread`?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `TDWResponseType.FromJsonString<T>` generic type `T` must be either explicitly defined or must be available as `T` from the outer context. There is not `T` available in the outer context and such code will not compile.

In your particular case, either `MyThread` class must be generic class or `Execute` method must be generic method.

Assuming that `MyThread` class is `TThread` descendant, then modifying `Execute` method is out of option.

You have two options:

- declare `MyThread<T>` instead of `MyThread`
- use specific class in `TDWResponseType.FromJsonString<TSomeClass>`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys:

```
procedure TMyThread<T>.Execute;  // with: TMyThread<T: class, constructor>=class(TThread)
begin
  TJson.JsonToObject<T>(Response);
end;
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially Olivier's and Dalija's suggestion?

Comment: Yes it is, and I thank them. I'm just answering my own question...